# Facebook Graph API - JSON data

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I am getting the following data in JSON format by the Facebook graph API. However it looks like it is in invalid JSON format. The JSON formatter says that the error is in line 1. What is this error ?

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            application =             {
                id = 2409997254;
                name = Likes;
            };
            "created_time" = "2013-05-05T07:51:41+0000";
            from =             {
                id = 100000347121257;
                name = "Rishab Gulati";
            };
            id = "notif_746853089_182660043";
            link = "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151457234013090&set=a.427064503089.223857.746853089&type=1";
            object = "<null>";
            title = "Rishab Gulati, Deepika Gurnani and 2 other people like your photo.";
            to =             {
                id = 746853089;
                name = "Ashish Agarwal";
            };
            unread = 1;
            "updated_time" = "2013-05-05T10:48:33+0000";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/746853089/notifications?format=json&access_token=**xxxxxxxxxx";
        previous = "https://graph.facebook.com/746853089/notifications?format=json&access_token=**SNIP**&limit=5000&since=1367740301&__paging_token=notif_746853089_182660043&__previous=1";
    };
    summary =     {
        "unseen_count" = 1;
        "updated_time" = "2013-05-05T10:48:33+0000";
    };
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt this data is coming from the Graph API. And yes, its very much invalid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

This data is incorrect and isn't what Facebook supplies

```
{
   "data": [
      {
```

Where as your JSON above shows

```
{
    data =     (
                {
```

There is a `(` when there should be a `{`

Also consider not giving your access token out in public.